# PHP NumberFormatter parseCurrency returning false

Tags: php

I'm trying this:

```
 public static function money($str)
    {
        $currency = 'BRL';
        $formatter = new \NumberFormatter('pt_BR', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

        return $formatter->parseCurrency($str, $currency);
    }
```

I'm trying to parse a string like "R$ 123,45" to "123.45", but it returns `false` everytime.

According to ISO 4217 `BRL` is the CODE for Brazil currency: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
 public function currency($str, $currency = 'BRL')
 {
     // use of NumberFormatter from extension //

     $formatter = new \NumberFormatter('pt_BR', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
     return $formatter->formatCurrency($str, $currency);
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to format the value, i want to parse (remove the currency symbols and etc...) to a normal value, you'r formatting the value. I'm trying to use `$formatter->parseCurrency`, you used `$formatter->formatCurrency`